# Meaning of code outlining in the context of programming

Tags: translation, programming

Currently I'm translating a book regarding programming. In one section the developement environment [LiteIDE](//github.com/visualfc/liteide) and it's features are mentioned. One of them is `code outlining`.

Since I can't find any proper translation in German dictionaries, I would like to ask you.

Comment: This forum may not be the right place for this question, but outline in this context probably means "a general description or plan giving the essential features of something but not the detail."

Comment: Code umschreiben (in Deutsch/in German).

Comment: I was going to suggest umschreiben as well.

Comment: @GetzelR At the beginning I had the same thought, but Stackoverflow also doesn't seem to be the right place for translation questions.

Comment: @user3147268 either way, I think you've got your answer...

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about "flowcharting"?

Comment: @hotlicks Flowcharting wouldn't be the right context. If you take a look at the linked website in the quesrion you'll see in the feature section that the original developers of the editor mention 'Class view and outline' as a function.

Comment: There are various schemes for "structure diagrams" and the like, though the terminology isn't very "firm".

Comment: In an IDE, "outlining" might refer to hiding the details of code, so it just shows the general structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Code outlining" is a concept well-known to the prior generation of programmers (ie, those familiar with "structured programming").  It simply means producing an "outline" of some computer code, conceptually very much similar to an "outline" of ordinary written text (such as you encountered in English composition class).

The "outline" may be written in plain English (though usually with some indentation or `{}` characters or some such to indicate "scope"), or in "pseudo-code" (which looks, at a distance, like "real" code, but, on close inspection, contains English phrases instead of code expressions.  Or the "outline" may be produced in the form of a "flow chart", which is a graphical representation of the program logic.

I have encountered various tools, over my career, which purport to "automate" the translation between outline and "real" code, but have never found them to be particularly effective -- translating either direction generally involves manual effort (ie, actual thought).

Answer (score -1):

Hm, I am a programmer and not sure what that is supposed to be.

A common feature of modern IDEs is syntax highlighting. Keywords are colored in order to make the code more readable. For example

- string literals in green
- numbers in blue
- classes and interfaces in a dark blue
- comments in gray

In german there's not really a good translation, I've seen *Syntaxhervorhebung*

Other possible features that sound close to *code outlining *

- bracket matching
- error outlining

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment ?